# Request for SQL idea on creating news db

Tags: wordpress

I recently discover wordpress and I bought a template called " newspaper " , I got confortable with it but I really have no idea what to create on it database

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get what you want here, but you have to create the database (in phpMyAdmin or something, add a user with privileges) and than you can install wordpress. Does not have much to do with the theme or template as you call it.